# Shortcut to calculate eigenvectors of submatrix of symmetric PSD matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Let $A$ be a symmetric PSD matrix,   $0\leq \lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 \leq  \dots \leq \lambda_n  $ are the eigenvalues. $v_i$ are the corresponding eigenvectors.

Derive a submatrix $B$ by eliminating the **jth** row and column from $A$. How to calculate (or approximate) the eigenvectors/eigenvalues of $B$ from that of $A$.

**Cauchy interlacing theorem** separates the eigenvalues of $A$ and that of $B$:
 $$
  0\leq  \lambda_1 \leq \mu_1  \leq  \lambda_2  \leq \mu_2 \leq  \dots \leq  \mu_{n-2} \leq \lambda_{n-1} \leq \mu_{n-1} \leq \lambda_n
 $$
where $\mu_1 \leq \mu_2 \leq  \dots \leq \mu_{n-1}  $ are $B$'s eigenvalues.

**Schur complement** seems relevant. PB Denton's **eigenvectors from eigenvalues** says

$$
|v_{i,j}|^2 \Pi_{k=1;k\neq i}^n ( \lambda_i -\lambda_k)= \Pi_{k=1}^{n-1} ( \lambda_i -\mu_k)
$$

But I am not able to put pieces together:  how to compute/approximate the submatrix's ith eigenvectors/eigenvalues from that of the full matrix?

Comment: For others reading this: [this is the paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.03795) being referred to.  $v_i$ is the $i$th UNIT eigenvector of $A$, and $v_{i,j}$ denotes the $j$th entry of $v_i$.

Comment: The formula does not give you a way to produce the eigenvectors of $B$ from the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$.  It might give you a way to produce the **eigenvalues** of $B$ from the from the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$.  

In particular, the $n$ (non-linear) equations that are produced by taking $i = 1,\dots,n$ in the equation can perhaps be solved for $\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n$.